# Java- synchronizing a list

Tags: java, arraylist, synchronization

I've been stuck on this one for a while, so any help is greatly appreciated.

I have the following code section:

```
BallThread.java
@Override
public synchronized void run() {
  while (numItersCompleted < maxNumIters) {
    completedThisIter = false;
synchronized (ballList) {
    for (Ball b : ballList) { // line 35
        b.updatePosition(ballPanel.getBounds(), ballList);
    }
}
 } // other stuff


Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.ArrayList$SubList.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:1091)
at java.util.ArrayList$SubList.listIterator(ArrayList.java:972)
at java.util.AbstractList.listIterator(AbstractList.java:300)
at java.util.ArrayList$SubList.iterator(ArrayList.java:968)
at Part2.BallThread.run(BallThread.java:35)
```

And sometimes I get this(line 36 in BallPanel)

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:782)
at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:754)
at Part2.BallPanel.paintComponent(BallPanel.java:36)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1029)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5138)
at javax.swing.BufferStrategyPaintManager.paint(BufferStrategyPaintManager.java:302)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1188)
at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5086)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4896)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:783)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:735)
```

Comment: Why are your methods `synchronized`? Making the `paintComponent` method `synchronized` is pointless because it should only ever be called from the *Event Dispatch Thread*.

Comment: To prevent race. If this is not a solution, what should I do instead?

Comment: I am giving these code segments because that is where the exception instances point to.

Comment: Are you sure these are the only two segments of code that are modifying `ballList`? What does `Ball.updatePosition` do?

Comment: b.updatePosition modifies each element inside the ballList, but does not  modify the list itself.

Comment: Are there any other segments of code where you modify `ballList`?

Comment: `b.updatePosition(ballPanel.getBounds(), ballList)` looks suspicious because `ballList` is passed to it ..

Comment: I tried removing ballist as an argumet to b.updatePosition, it does not solve the problem

Comment: Could you show us how ballList is declared and initialized in each class?  (And any other uses of it that may be relevant in your code.)

Comment: Nowhere in the code you've provided is the structure of either `ballList` modified.  It/they have to be modified somewhere or it would never have any elements.  Where is it being added to?

Comment: Need to see `getBalls()` on `BallThread` too.  (It seems it may not be returning a mere reference to `ballList`.)

Comment: does `ballThreads[threadIndex].getBalls()` return a copy? if so, you will not be synchronizing on the same object as your iterating code in the thread and panel.

Comment: No, what it does is  public List<Ball> getBalls() {
     return ballList;
    }

Comment: For initialization, I use private final List<Ball> ballList = Collections.synchronizedList(...); as Jeffrey recommended

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing the rest of your code, one fix would be to declare `ballList` as the following:

```
private final List<Ball> ballList = Collections.synchronizedList(...);
```

All of the operations of a [`synchronizedList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList%28java.util.List%29) attempt to synchronize on itself before every method, which would make your iterations completely safe as long as you keep your current `synchronized(ballList)`s in place.

Comment: But ballList is getting modified along the way, how can I declare it as final?

Comment: Declaring a variable `final` just means that you cannot change its reference. You can still modify the object it points to. (You cannot do `ballList = null`, but you can still do `ballList.add(...)`.) It's not necessary, but in concurrent programs, `final` fields are generally safer than non-`final` fields.

Comment: I tried it, it didn't work. I put those lines you showed above in every class that has a reference to a ballList, still the same problem remained.

Comment: I added the code that actually modifies the array list, which when I comment out, I don't have any problems. So how do I synchronize on it?

Comment: It is in private synchronized void processCollisions() where it says DO STUFF, it actually adds elements to the array list

Comment: @Trup You should only use `Collections.synchronizedList` when you create the original `ballList`. Everything after that doesn't need to re-synchronize the `List`, it's already synchronized!

Comment: So, you are saying, rather than BallThread(List<Ball> ballList,JPanel ballPanel, CyclicBarrier barrier, long maxNumIters, int threadId) {
     //this.ballList = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<Ball>(ballList);
     this.ballList =  ballList = Collections.synchronizedList(ballList);
     this.ballPanel = ballPanel;
     this.barrier = barrier;
     this.threadId = threadId;
     this.maxNumIters = maxNumIters;
    } I actually need to instantiate the List as synchronized where I create it in the first place?

Comment: @Trup Yup. That way every thread will get the same `synchronizedList` object and each `synchronized` block will be using the same object.

Comment: I added it in the original question. So, you say instead of doing that, I should actually do it where I construct the original BallList?\

Answer (score 1):

In the code we can see here, `ballList` not actually being modified and reading with multiple threads is safe. Some other piece of code is likely modifying `ballList` (@pst above pointed out that it may be `updatePosition`).

The `run` and `paintComponent` methods don't look like they need to be synchronized either since they are not sharing state outside (since you are synchronizing on `ballList` in the relevant parts of the code).

EDIT:

Based on your edit, it looks like `processCollisions` only sycnhronizes on `ballsLocal` for one short block, not for when `ballsLocal` is not actually being modified

```
synchronized (ballsLocal) {             
  initialSize = ballsLocal.size();
}
```

Although `processCollisions` is synchronized, that implicitly synchronizes on `this`. If your methods that just use the `synchronized` keyword without specifying what to synchronize on are in different classes, the `this` being synchronized on is different. If you need to synchronize across different classes like that, either the ball class should handle the synchronization or you need a lock that is shared.

Comment: This doesn't solve anything, removing the synchronized from them cannot make things better.

Comment: But the fact that the OP is getting `ConcurrentModificationException`s from both loops makes me believe that another thread may be involved in this.

Comment: Yes, I agree that something else must be modifying it (that's the second sentence in my answer). Removing the synchronization in run/paintComponent will hopefully just clear up some clutter and make the issue a little easier to isolate.

Comment: @JeffStorey If `updatePosition` was modifying the `List` while iteration was in progress, you would only see `ConcurrentModificationException`s coming from that loop, not both.

Comment: Good point. Either way, we're in agreement that something is modifying the list.

Comment: Sorry for forgetting that. Please check out my updates. I still don't know how to synchronize it though. I guess that the synchronized keyword only happens when the accessing is done by the same kind of objects (of the same class).

Comment: Are processCollisions and your other two threads synchronizing on the same object?

Comment: Yes, if by 'the same object' you mean the same ballThreads arrayList, then yes

Comment: I did, above, it is the processCollisions()

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14318/discussion-between-jeff-storey-and-trup)

Comment: You say "either the ball class should handle the synchronization or you need a lock that is shared." Any idea / example how can I do this? I think I should explicitly handle a lock on the ballList array, but I don't know how to do this. An example would be of great help

Comment: I think you're close by synchronizing on the ballList array itself, but in the block where you modify the list, be sure that is also surrounded in `synchronized (ballList)`. Just synchronizing the methods doesn't actually make them thread safe if they are synchronized on different objects.

Comment: Another alternative if you don't want to deal with the synchronziation explicitly and you have a lot more reads on the list than writes, you can use `CopyOnWriteArrayList` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html

Comment: I tried it, it makes things too slow. So, how can I learn to synchronize explicitly? Any good examples?

Comment: Just search for Java synchronization. There are plenty of examples. Be sure to only synchronize what you need to otherwise your code can quickly bottleneck in synchronized blocks

Answer (score 0):

In your `processCollisions()`, you are adding objects to the list outside of the synchronized block.  Note that only *one* line appears to be synchronized, the one that gets the size, yet later on (near the end) you are adding to the list.  You need to not close the synchronized block until after your loops are finished.

Comment: @Trup Is there more to `processCollisions()` that you aren't showing us?  (The comment at the end implies there might be.)  Perhaps it has a similar issue?

Comment: @Trup I'm not seeing it.  I'm talking about after the comment that says "Then, process collisions across threads".  Is there anything after that?